# JPanel no se muestra si no modifico tamaño JFrame

Tags: java, jframe

Estoy haciendo pruebas con Java y al crear un entorno gráfico tengo el problema que el JPanel, panelPrincipal, solo se muestra si modifico manualmente el tamaño de mi Jframe. He provado con diferentes tamaños del JFrame y con diferentes Layouts pero nada me ha servido... Alguna idea?

Codigo de la clase de JFrame:

```
public class GUI extends JFrame{

/**
 * Constructor de la clase GUI para el entorno grafico
 */
public GUI() {
    // Heu d'inicialitzar les variables d'instància
    super();
    makeFrame();
}

public void makeFrame() {

    JButton entradasButton;
    JButton trabajadoresButton;
    JButton largerButton;

    PeticionesGUI peticionesGUI;
    peticionesGUI = new PeticionesGUI();

    // Creacion del frame principal
    this.setTitle("Parque de Atracciones V 0.1");
    this.setSize(800,600);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    //Creacion panel Principal       
    JPanel panelPrincipal = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    this.add(panelPrincipal);

    // Creacion menu principal
    JPanel toolbar = new JPanel();
    toolbar.setLayout(new GridLayout(10, 10));

    //Boton Entradas
    entradasButton = new JButton("Entradas");
    entradasButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            peticionesGUI.entradas(panelPrincipal);
        }
    });
    toolbar.add(entradasButton);

    //Boton Trabajadores
    trabajadoresButton = new JButton("Trabajadores");
    trabajadoresButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        peticionesGUI.trabajadores(panelPrincipal);
    }
                       });
    toolbar.add(trabajadoresButton);

    largerButton = new JButton("Larger");
    largerButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { }
                       });
    toolbar.add(largerButton);           

    this.add(toolbar, BorderLayout.WEST);
}
```

}

Código del método JPanel:

```
public void entradas(JPanel panelPrincipal){

    JLabel labelUsername = new JLabel("Nombre Cliente: ");
    JLabel labelPassword = new JLabel("Identificacion: ");
    JTextField txtnombreCliente = new JTextField(20);
    JTextField txtnifCliente = new JTextField(20);
    JButton buttonLogin = new JButton("Crear Entrada");


    panelPrincipal.removeAll();
    panelPrincipal.repaint();
    GridBagConstraints constraints = new GridBagConstraints();
    constraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
    constraints.insets = new Insets(50, 10, 10, 50);

    // add components to the panel
    constraints.gridx = 0;
    constraints.gridy = 0;     
    panelPrincipal.add(labelUsername, constraints);

    constraints.gridx = 1;
    panelPrincipal.add(txtnombreCliente, constraints);

    constraints.gridx = 0;
    constraints.gridy = 1;     
    panelPrincipal.add(labelPassword, constraints);

    constraints.gridx = 1;
    panelPrincipal.add(txtnifCliente, constraints);

    constraints.gridx = 0;
    constraints.gridy = 2;
    constraints.gridwidth = 2;
    constraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
    panelPrincipal.add(buttonLogin, constraints);

    // set border for the panel
    panelPrincipal.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(
            BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(), "Gestor Entradas"));

    buttonLogin.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            Cliente persona;

            String nombreCliente = (txtnombreCliente.getText());
            String nifCliente = (txtnifCliente.getText());
            persona = new Entrada(nombreCliente, nifCliente, 24);
        }
    });

}
```

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: necesitaría ver más código para opinar. Saludos

Comment: @AlbertoLopez he pegado el código completo. Muchas gracias!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ferran, quizás te convenga leer de este Layout https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html

Con este Layout puedes cambiar los páneles y no tener que estarlos creando cada vez.

Ahora que si prefieres tu esquema, intenta agregando esta línea:

```
  panelPrincipal.updateUI();
```

antes de esta línea:

```
   panelPrincipal.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(
           BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(), "Gestor Entradas"));
```

Te muestro como cambiaría tu programa con el uso de CardLayout:

```
public class GUI extends JFrame implements java.awt.event.ActionListener {

    private JPanel panelPrincipal;
/**
 * Constructor de la clase GUI para el entorno grafico
*/
public GUI() {

    super();
    makeFrame();
}

@Override //aquí escuchamos a los botones
public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evento) {
    CardLayout layout = (CardLayout)(panelPrincipal.getLayout());
    layout.show(panelPrincipal, evento.getActionCommand()); 
     //getActionCommand() te da el nombre que le pusiste al botón. 
     //Aunque lo puedes cambiar via button.setActionCommand("otro nombre");
 }

public void makeFrame() {

    //Creacion panel Principal       
    JPanel panelPrincipal = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    this.add(panelPrincipal);

    JPanel entradasPanel = creaEntradasPanel();
    JPanel trabajadoresPanel = creaTrabajadoresPanel();

    panelPrincipal.add(entradasPanel, "Entradas");
    panelPrincipal.add(trabajadoresPanel, "Trabajadores");

    JButton entradasButton;
    JButton trabajadoresButton;
    JButton largerButton;

    PeticionesGUI peticionesGUI;
    peticionesGUI = new PeticionesGUI();

    // Creacion del frame principal
    this.setTitle("Parque de Atracciones V 0.1");
    this.setSize(800,600);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


    // Creacion menu principal
    JPanel toolbar = new JPanel();
    toolbar.setLayout(new GridLayout(10, 10));

    //Boton Entradas
    entradasButton = new JButton("Entradas");
    entradasButton.addActionListener(this);
    ///tu clase GUI ahora implementa el ActionListener y escucha ambos botones

    toolbar.add(entradasButton);

    //Boton Trabajadores
    trabajadoresButton = new JButton("Trabajadores");
    trabajadoresButton.addActionListener(this);
    ///tu clase GUI ahora implementa el ActionListener y escucha ambos botones

    toolbar.add(trabajadoresButton);

    largerButton = new JButton("Larger");
    largerButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { }
                   });
    toolbar.add(largerButton);           

    this.add(toolbar, BorderLayout.WEST);
}
```

Para tu método entradas, lo cambiaría así:

```
public JPanel creaEntradas(){
    JPanel entradasPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());

    //etc, etc,

    //quitaría estas dos líneas:
    //panelPrincipal.removeAll();
    //panelPrincipal.repaint();

    // etc, etc.

    return entradasPanel;
}
```

Y así para los que requieras agregar. No lo he compilado, pero es para que tomes la idea.

Comment: Muchas gracias. De momento he utilizado panelPrincipal.updateUI(); Pero en breve leere el artículo que me has comentado. Por lo que veo mi opcion es muy chapuza, no? ;)

Comment: no sé a que te refieras con chapuza. Tu opción puede funcionar, pero si hay una opción que le queda a la medida, yo la usaría. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba agregando el *Jpanel* al *JFrame* antes de estas 2 lineas de código del *JFrame*:

`setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);` y `setVisible(true);`

Yo tenía el mismo problema y haciendo esto lo solucioné!

**Ejemplo:**

```
...

this.add(panelPrincipal);

setVisible(true);

setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

...
```