# Al ejecutar el programa muestra el panel en blanco

Tags: java, java-swing

Lo que pasa que cuando ejecuto o inicio el programa me deja en blanco, pero cuando hago maximizar y re-maximizar ahí sí que me aparece el panel de lo que creé:

Dejo las capturas:

Al ejecutar:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al maximizar

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Incluso cambié la resolución y el resultado da lo mismo.

El código:

```
package NavengandoPestañas;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

/**
 *
* @author PC2-LAB4-USUARIO
*/
public class  Ventana  extends  JFrame{
Pestañas pestasa = new Pestañas ();
  public Ventana (String titulo){
     super(titulo);
     setSize(800,600);
     setLocation(100,100);
     setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setVisible(true);
    }
 }
```

Comment: Las preguntas que buscan ayuda con la depuración deben incluir el comportamiento esperado, un problema específico o error, y el código más corto necesario para reproducirlo en la propia pregunta. Las preguntas sin un planteamiento claro del problema no son útiles para otros lectores. Véase: [mcve]

Comment: El código que pusiste diría que Pestañas no está definido, y no se podría correr

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [JPanel no se muestra si no modifico tamaño JFrame](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/247404/jpanel-no-se-muestra-si-no-modifico-tama%c3%b1o-jframe)

Comment: No, no responde es otra cosa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con algunas modificaciones tu código queda así para hacer que se pueda ver el problema:

```
package navengandopestanhas;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class  Ventana  extends JFrame {
    //Pestañas pestasa = new Pestañas ();
    public Ventana (String titulo){
        super(titulo);
        setSize(800,600);
        setLocation(100,100);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Ventana v = new Ventana("ola mundo");
    }
}
```

como verás corregí los nombres de clase y paquete con acentos para descartar qeu fuera problema de codificación.

el paquete lo puse en minúsculas para evitar problemas en windows si lo modificas después.

Pero lo relevante es el ciclo de vida,

estás metiendo el proceso de pintado junto con la creación dentro del constructor así que lo que pasará es que

Primero se creará, luego se hará visible.

Y después de eso cualquier cosa que le agregues después no se verá porque no está antes del

```
setVisible(true);
```

Cómo se corrige?

Usa el principio S de SOLID, que se traduciría como una sola responsabilidad.

Que tu constructor construya tu objeto (poner el título y otros valores de variables) y que tu pintado esté aparte, te dejo un ejemplo de como lo haría yo en un primer intento.

```
public class  Ventana  extends JFrame {
    //Pestañas pestasa = new Pestañas ();
    public Ventana (String titulo){
        super(titulo);
       pintado();
    }

    private void pintado(){
        setSize(800,600);
        setLocation(100,100);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        agregarComponentesPersonalizados();

        setVisible(true);
    }

    public agregarComponentesPersonalizados(){
        // aquí agregas lo que sea dinámico y quieras pintar como por ejemplo digamos unas pestañas que obtienes de una consulkta a una base de datos.
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Ventana v = new Ventana("ola mundo");
    }
}
```